# Pseudo-selectors acting strangely with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on an experimental site with a fellow student of mine and I am running into an issue with jQuery and CSS selectors. Let me give you a recap of the issues I am seeing. In my CSS I am chaining pseudo-selectors to do some simple nth-based styling like so:

HTML:

```
<ul class="formatted-list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

I am targeting things with nths like so:

CSS:

```
.formatted-list li:nth-child(odd) { ... }
.formatted-list li:first-child:first-letter { ... }
```

The first selector is working correctly in both CSS and jQuery. However, when I try to target the following code:

```
$('.formatted-list li:first-child:first-letter')
```

I am not returning an element. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector is not in the jQuery [**api docs**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

I don't see another way to do this then this:

```
$('.formatted-list li:first-child').text().substr(0,1);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eR87e/4/)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are trying to target an object in jQuery you can't get the first letter that way. 
You are working with an object, not a string.

The first example is targeting all odd objects, but the second one is targeting the object string (a.k.a the first letter).

So you should split your code a little, first to take the object text and then to take it's first letter.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was under the impression that it simply used CSS selectors to target everything.

Answer (score 1):

to capitalize the first letter of every list item, do this:

```
$('.formatted-list li').each(function(idx) {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.slice(1));
});
```

here's another pure css solution to capitalize the first letter of each word in the list item:

```
.formatted-list li {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```